# proto.Marshal out of memory

Tags: go, out-of-memory, proto

we use github.com/gogo/protobuf, I get service crash at `proto.Marshal()`, this happens almost once a day,But I did not receive a memory alarm，This looks like a memory leak，has anyone encountered this situation?

```
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xe25648, 0x16)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:617 +0x72
runtime.sysMap(0xc5cc000000, 0xc490000000, 0x18671b8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:170 +0xc7
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x184e180, 0xc48d3d8000, 0x184e190, 0x62469ec)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:633 +0x1cd
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x184e180, 0x62469ec, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1222 +0x42
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0x184e180, 0x62469ec, 0x18671c8, 0x7f213328e6d8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1150 +0x37f
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x184e180, 0x62469ec, 0x7f21bed20101, 0x184e190)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:977 +0xc2
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1048 +0x4c
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x184e180, 0x62469ec, 0xc000000101, 0x7f21bed2a0e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1047 +0x8a
runtime.largeAlloc(0xc48d3d8000, 0xffffffffffff0100, 0x7f21bed2a0e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1055 +0x99
runtime.mallocgc.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:950 +0x46
runtime.systemstack(0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:351 +0x66
runtime.mstart()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1153

goroutine 521107 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:311 fp=0xc0982eae30 sp=0xc0982eae28 pc=0x45cdf0
runtime.mallocgc(0xc48d3d8000, 0x0, 0x1700, 0xc492070000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:949 +0x872 fp=0xc0982eaed0 sp=0xc0982eae30 pc=0x40e6d2
runtime.growslice(0xca6f00, 0xc492070000, 0x1c43, 0x2000, 0xc48d3d6e73, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:175 +0x151 fp=0xc0982eaf38 sp=0xc0982eaed0 pc=0x4462a1
xxxx/vendor/github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto.(*Buffer).EncodeStringBytes(...)

xxxx/vendor/github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto.Marshal(0xf58840, 0xc45eda2a00, 0x2d, 0x1, 0xc1e72e7801, 0x1, 0xc4860713e0)
    /opt/go/src/xxxx/vendor/github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto/encode.go:236 +0x92 fp=0xc0982eb9a8 sp=0xc0982eb960 pc=0x79dd12
xxxx/feature_server_user/get_feature.(*GetUserFeatureAction).Handler(0x1864ca8, 0xc46a746a00, 0x17, 0x200, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
```

Comment: No, and it is pretty hard to help you understand what is going on without your code.

Comment: Could be a memory leak anywhere in your program, or could be memory use by another process on the same system, or could be an oversized pb payload, or any number of other things. There's no context provided to offer any insight.